# C# Syntax Highlighting for Confluence

Tags: c#, java, syntax-highlighting, confluence

Does anyone know of any C# syntax highlighter plugins for Confluence? Using the default Java highlighter works, but it misses things like string in C# and String in Java, with the latter being highlighted and the former plain black text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a so called newcode macro that allows a lot of different languages. See https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/NCODE/Confluence+New+Code+Macro for the macro itself.

To use the macro, just enclose your code into

```
{newcode:csharp}...{newcode}
```

With newer versions of this macro (or newer versions of Confluence itself), you are free to use the macro name `newcode` or `code`. Since version 4.x of Confluence, the visual editor supports the finding of macros much better, so just start typing: `{code` which results then in

[image]

In the then opening macro editor, you may select directly the language (and some other parameters):

[image]

Comment: I had to use `{code:lang-csharp}` to specify the language.  I think newer versions of the newcode macro support `{code}` or `{newcode}`.

Comment: I was able to start typing `{code`, and once I chose `Code Block` from the autocomplete list, I was able to click on it to create it, and then click `Edit` to get to the macro editor described above.